# I am getting the following wrror while i tried to do node <file name> and also truffle test <file name>

Tags: truffle

```
Error: Cannot find module 'web3'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\tuffle\toke.test.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:250:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:247:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:576:10)
    at resolve (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\test.js:116:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\test.js:115:1)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Truffle v5.0.33 (core: 5.0.33)
Node v10.15.0

Comment: Do you have node_modules folder in your project directory?

Answer (score 3):

Execute in console:

```
npm install web3
```

Make sure that the node_modules folder is in your project directory.